# Using grep on a Python command output into a shell script

Tags: python, shell, variables, redhat

I've been struggling for the past two hours on this simple example :

I have this line:

```
python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'
```

Which gives:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id
{'arch': 'ia32e',
 'basearch': 'x86_64',
 'releasever': '7Server',
 'uuid': 'd68993fd-059a-4753-a7ab-1c4a601d206f',
 'yum8': 'rhel',
 'yum9': '7.1'}
```

And now, I would just like to get the line with the 'releasever'.

Directly on my Linux, there is no problem:

```
$ python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)' | grep releasever
 'releasever': '7Server',
```

I have the answer I am looking for.

But when it comes to put it in a script, I am so helpless.

Currently, I have:

```
#!/bin/ksh
check="$(python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)')"


echo "${check}"
# The echo works as expected. But now, I would like to do a grep on that variable:

check2=${check}|grep releasever

echo "${check2}"
```

And the result is empty.

I've tried a lot of different things, like brackets, parentheses, quote, double quote, all-in-one command, but I can't get what I want. 
I don't know what's happening behind that code, which is very simple. But still…

Can someone help me?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do it all in a Python script rather than abuse `python -c` and then bash the output?

Comment: I roiled back your edit. Accepting the answer which helped you is quite sufficient; your question should remain strictly a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not putting `check` in any kind of std input. This would work fine:

```
check2=$(echo "$check" | grep releasever)
```

or you could put `check` content into a file and do like `grep <string> < <file>`.

Comment: This is missing a command substitution. Right now it will try to run a command `"$check"`.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your quick answer. It worked perfeclty. :) I did not think I would have to print the result of a variable again. For me, a variable allows to stock the output of a command so that you can do a grep on it or something. It's strange, but I am quite new to that. I'll remember it for the next time.

Comment: Probably don't suggest a [useless `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be 3 options.

It looks like `yb.conf.yumvar` is a dictionary. In which case, you could either print `yb.conf.yumvar['releasever']` directory in your python script in which case the grep would be unnecessary.

Secondly, don't use grep. Instead, have your python script parse the `yb.conf.yumvar` into json and print it and then use `jq` from the outside to print the value of `releasever`

Third, and this is the sanest way, do what you want in Python directly. `ksh` scripts will be harder to manage over a longer period of time so just do what you want to do in Python and us `os.system` to execute external programs.